# How to avoid User Controls Overlapping while draging in wpf canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am adding user controls dynamically to my canvas. i want to avoid overlapping of user controls while draging. i am checking position of every control. is there any easy solution or proper way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

That's precisely one of the things that a canvas enables you to do: Enable you to overlap. Why don't you use instead a grid width automatic or take-what-rest space (`width/height = auto/*`) respectively, so that each control use its required space (`auto`) or the rest of the available space (`*`).